# Remove specific numbers from matrix and obtain a new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, I have the matrix:

```
A = [1 3 5; 
     2 7 3; 
     9 3 8];
```

I want to remove the number `3` from matrix `A`, thus obtaining a new matrix:

```
B = [1 5; 
     2 7; 
     9 8];
```

If I try to simply remove it with `A=A(A~=3)`, it just gives me a column vector without number `3`, but I want a matrix with the exact changed size. Anyone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: Will each row always have the exact same number of `3`s?

Comment: No, not necessarily. I just gave a simple example. I actually have much larger matrices that I have to handle.

Comment: So then you're going to have to store your output as a cell array as the result might have a different number of elements in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic solution:

```
B = arrayfun(@(r)(A(r,A(r,:)~=3)), 1:size(A,1), 'Uni', false)'
```

which outputs a cell array and makes no assumptions about how many `3`s there are per row.

For illustration, I will rewrite the above line as a for-loop:

```
for r = 1:size(A,1)
    row = A(r,:)
    B(r) = row(row~=3)
end
```

If all your rows contain an equal number of 3s then see [Santhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527028/1011724)

Or else according to your new requirements from the comments just:

```
A(A==3) = NaN;
```

or if you want to eliminate more than just one number

```
A(ismember(A, [2,3])) = NaN
```

Comment: As I said, the 3s can be randomly distributed, not necessarily repeat the same times in each row, or not even be contained in each row. I tried your one line code, but it gives me a 1x3 cell array, and I want a 3x2 double array, like @Santhan obtained.

Comment: @user3611812 yes but those two criteria (i.e. randomly distributed `3`s and numerical matrix output) are contradictory. What should `B` look like if `A = [1,2,3;3,3,4;1,2,2]`?

Comment: The problem is that I have a non-square 250x16224 matrix, and I want to remove the 3s, and reshape it into a new matrix. It's more difficult that the simple example that I gave..

Comment: @user3611812 i made an assumption that number of 3's each row are same. That is what you gave as an example. Else you need to store the results as a cell array like dan's solution or my alternate solution. What results do you expect for dan's example in the comment?

Comment: @user3611812 yes exactly why I'm asking you to define `B` for a more complex `A`. Please tell me what `B` looks like when `A = [1,2,3;3,3,4;1,2,2]`? Because it's either going to be a cell array or else you're going to have to specify some sort of row padding protocal such as `NaN`s padding the ends of each row...

Comment: It would probably have to look like this: `B = [1,2,NaN;NaN,NaN,4;1,2,2]`

Comment: @user3611812 So then `A(A==3) = NaN` is your solution

Comment: I should have thought more intrusively, sorry, because I have a big non-square matrix to analyze.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to convert more numbers, like 2 and 3 from A into NaN in one single code line? I would get `B = [1,NaN,NaN;NaN,NaN,4;1,NaN,NaN]`

Comment: @Dan Thank you, I appreciate it. One more thing.. how could I convert all numbers above 2 for example in NaN in matrix A?

Comment: @user3611812 come on, you can work that out yourself :/ `A(A>2) = NaN`. Are you going to accept this answer btw?

Comment: I already did it, thanks. Yes, I made a small mistake in the code and I thought this code is not working.

Answer (score 2):

One Alternate, assuming each row containing equal number of `3's`

```
A = [1 3 5; 2 7 3; 9 3 8];
B = A.';                   %//'
out = reshape(B(B~=3),[],size(A,1)).'
```

**Results:**

```
A =

 1     3     5
 2     7     3
 9     3     8


out =

 1     5
 2     7
 9     8
```

---

**Note:** If the number of 3's in each rows are not equal, see the Generic solution by @Dan in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30526954/2111163)

Or here is other alternative using `mat2cell` & `cellfun`

**Code:**

```
%// creating cells where each cell contain one row
AC = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2));

%// returning only the elements not equal to 3 in each row
out = cellfun(@(x) x(x~=3),AC,'uni',0)
```

**Results:**

```
A =

 1     3     5     3
 2     7     3     1
 9     3     8     5


out = 

[1x2 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x3 double]
```